# Creating table 'ShoppingCart' in MySQL - error 1005

Tags: mysql

I've created a table in MySQL named 'ShoppingCart', but it shows error 1005. What's the mistake here?

```
 mysql> create table ShoppingCart(
    -> Current_Purchases varchar(100),
    -> Previous_Purchases varchar(100),
    -> Phone_No int(20),
    -> constraint fk_shop foreign key (Phone_No) references Registration(Phone_No));
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'infoproject.shoppingcart' (errno: 150)
```

The other table 'Registration' is already created and the same column is present with the same datatype.

Comment: Create an index on `Phone_no` in both columns

Comment: Is `phone_no` the primary key of the `registration` table (or at least has a unique constraint)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No I have'nt used any constraint for `Phone_no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column referenced by a foreign key has to be unique. In your case, it seems like the error is due to a non-unique `Phone_No` in `Registration`. Alter the `Registration` table to add a unique index on `Phone_No`.